# How to skip undefined item in ng-repeat using a filter?

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

Please consider this plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EGSiUxkmqwBhLVPgatRp

The 10th item should be filtered out.. I know how to filter on an item's property but i cant seem to be able to get it working for the item itself.

please help

Answer (score 1):

A cheat would be to filter by an empty string:

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{name : ''}">
```

But hardly ideal.

Another way would be to define your own filter that only returns items that are defined - something like:

```
.filter('removeUndefined', function(){
    return function(listitems){
        var results = [];
        angular.foreach(listitems, function(item, key){
            if(item != undefined){
                results.push(item);
            }
        });
        return results;
    }
})
```